# Only selecting a some of checkboxes in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

I have this code already in place:

```
function chkcontrol(j) {
    var total=0;
    for(var i=0; i < document.contactForm.qualities.length; i++) {
        if(document.contactForm.qualities[i].checked) {
            total =total +1;}
            if(total > 2) {
                alert("Please Select only 2")
                document.contactForm.qualities[j].checked = false ;
                return false;
             }
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine but when I put `name="qualities[]"` with the brackets it no longer works. Trying to add [] to:
`for(var i=0; i < document.contactForm.qualities.length; i++){`

returns an error.

EDIT HERE IS MY RELEVANT HTML:

```
<form name="contactForm" method="post" action="{$contact_action}" id="newform">
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="cfCSF">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="qualities[]" value="value" onclick="chkcontrol(0)"/> value</label><br />
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="qualities[]" value="value" onclick="chkcontrol(1)"/>value</label><br />
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="qualities[]" value="value" onclick="chkcontrol(2)"/> value</label><br />
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="qualities[]" value="value" onclick="chkcontrol(3)"/> value</label><br />
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="qualities[]" value="value" onclick="chkcontrol(4)"/> value</label><br /><br />
```

Comment: Can you add your HTML to your question? Is name="qualities[]" something you're trying to add in the HTML? Otherwise, I don't see name= anywhere in your js.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid; the only *valid* child elements of a `table` are `tbody`, `thead`, `tfoot` or `tr`. Any other content must be wrapped in `td` elements, and those elements, and `th` are the only valid child-elements of `tr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to use this:

```
function chkcontrol(j) {
    var total = 0;
    var chk = document.getElementById("newform").querySelectorAll('input[name="qualities[]"]');
    for (var i = 0; i < chk.length; i++) {
        var cur = chk[i];
        if (cur.checked) {
            total++;
            if (total > 2) {
                alert("Too many checked");
                chk[j].checked = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/zz395/

Another option, to organize everything better and keep the Javascript unobtrusive, is to use something like this:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var chk = document.getElementById("newform").querySelectorAll('input[name="qualities[]"]');
    for (var i = 0; i < chk.length; i++) {
        var cur = chk[i];
        addEvent(cur, "click", clickHandler);
    }
};

function clickHandler(e) {
    var total = 0;
    var chk = document.getElementById("newform").querySelectorAll('input[name="qualities[]"]');
    for (var i = 0; i < chk.length; i++) {
        var cur = chk[i];
        if (cur.checked) {
            total++;
            if (total > 2) {
                alert("Too many checked");
                preventDefault(e);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

function preventDefault(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        e.returnValue = false;
    }
}

function addEvent(element, eventName, callback) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(eventName, callback, false);
    } else if (element.attachEvent) {
        element.attachEvent("on" + eventName, callback);
    } else {
        element["on" + eventName] = callback;
    }
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/zz395/2/

(where the HTML doesn't have any `onclick` defined for the checkboxes)

I like this setup better because you don't need to hardcode the index of the checkbox, the `event` is prevented (instead of unchecking a checkbox manually, which I think works fine anyways).

Reference:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.querySelectorAll

Comment: You'll need to add the closing `]`, also it's maybe worth mentioning the compatibility issues of the selectors API (specifically in relation to IE < 8, I think).

Comment: @DavidThomas Yeah, I was testing in a different window and found that, thanks for pointing it out, and Musa for fixing it :)

Comment: @user2267668 It worked fine for me in a jsFiddle, but I'm sure my HTML/Javascript doesn't match up with what you're actually using. Update your original question with how you're using this function and the relevant HTML, otherwise you can't expect things to work out of the box

Comment: @user2267668 I just updated my answer with a few fixes - my fault. Thanks for posting the HTML so I could complete it. It looks to work for me.

Comment: lol. Its not your fault its mine. When you dont see the whole scope hard to understand the problem. That was my fault. Thank you for taking the time and helping me out!. It works perfectly.

Comment: @user2267668 Well thanks :) And no problem! I just updated my answer with another option, which I prefer, but it's up to you. Just wanted to provide you with some more information/example

Answer (score 1):

You need the square bracket notation to use object keys with characters that are not valid identifiers.

```
for(var i=0; i < document.contactForm["qualities[]"].length; i++){
```

This allows any valid string to be used as a key, while the identifier syntax will limit you to letters, numbers, `_` and `$`.

Comment: Yeah I would think this would work but it doesnt. I tried that also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.contactForm['qualities[]']` to select the list of form elements with `name="qualities[]"`